# Angularjs $anchorScroll.yOffset is not working for ng-sticky headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, sticky

My project build on Angular Material, Angular JS and I am using ngSticky for sticking header below main header(which is a md-toolbar).

In the second header(sticky), there are bunch of button which should work as a link for scrolling to different section in same page.(Upon clicking the buttons, the page should scroll to respective section).

I used following code

Angular Controller

```
$anchorScroll.yOffset = 100;  
$location.hash(anchor);
$anchorScroll();
```

HTML

```
<div sticky offset="65" media-query="min-width: 1000px" style="background-color:white; border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF;">
    <ng-include src="'XXX/XXX-buttons.html'"></ng-include>
    <div class="space-top-bottom"></div>
    <ng-include src="'XXX/XXX-links.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Note that the links are under `'<ng-include src="'XXX/XXX-links.html'"></ng-include>'`

Currently, page scrolls but not to correct position, it ignoring the sticky header height.

As per Angular JS [dos](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll), "In order for yOffset to work properly, scrolling should take place on the document's root and not some child element."

Expected behavior : Page should scroll to exact div id.

Problem :

> Unable to add add offset to the scroll which compensate header(sticky) height.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution,

```
$location.hash('current-div');
$anchorScroll();
$('#scrolling-div').animate({ scrollTop: $('#current-div').position().top - $('#sticky-div').height() }, "slow");
```

The idea is to animate on the div which has scoll in it, not the parent div.

Hope this help someone.